# Quill.js - Unable to get selection range on a readOnly:true editor in Quill.js 0.20.1 -

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

**Tool: Quill.js**
**USE CASE**
To let user select a text range in a readOnly editor and apply highlighting.

**Detailed Context**
I'm maintaining some code that's using Quill 0.20.1. I've created a readOnly:true editor to disable the content from getting changed. Even though text content in editor is readOnly I still want the user to be able to select, highlight and associate some metadata that references the selection made. (Basically I wanted to read what selection range the user made on quill editor)

So I tried the following:

```
readOnlyHighlightable.quill.editor.selection.getRange(); // And it did not work
```

And trying to listen on event "selection-change" also doesn't seem to get invoked by events.

```
readOnlyHighlightable.quill.on("selection-change", function (range) {
    console.log(range);
});
```

In contrast if I remove the readOnly flag from quill editor constructor it works well. Is this the desired behavior? Why is a readOnly editor not selectable?

Finally, I created a plain editor (theme: snow and formats: ["background"]) and I tried disabling the editor with the following function and still the range function doesn't return the selected range.

```
quill.editor.enable(false);
```

If I do not call the enable(false) function, getRange() works fine.

**Ref**
Range function:
quill.editor.selection.getRange();

Disable function:
quill.editor.enable(false);

PS. I'm excited about Quill 1.0 but this I've to implement this feature in Quill.js 0.20.1.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Quill selection works on the presumption that the editor is the current 'active' element. But from the browser's perspective, disabled content-editable div is not active. So you can work around this by setting tab index:1 on it so the browser returns true on "is active element"

```
$("#ql-editor-1").attr("tabIndex", 1);
myEditor.quill.editor.selection.getRange();
```

Hope this helps.